# How can I stop calling a method in [queryParams] in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement the open in a new tab option for the user. I should **not** use (click) to do that, so now I'm using the below logic to open in a new tab.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/search/' + search.id]" [queryParams]="getQueryParams()">Destination</a>
```

The problem is for `getQueryParams()` is called everytime and the app is very slow because of that. It is any way to don't call this method any time? Or to implement this open in a new tab in another way without 
 `(click)`?

Comment: What exactly does `getQueryParams` do? Can you paste the function code?

Comment: you can store the result of that call as a property in your controller and bind that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason why the queryParams are obtained through a function?

If not you can manually set the queryParams to a public property in your component and bind that to the queryParams property of the link.

Component:

```
  public queryParams;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.queryParams = this.getQueryParams();
  }
```

HTML:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/search/' + search.id]" [queryParams]="queryParams">Destination</a>
```